# Vertical alligement not proper display in word file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word c# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-core, dll

When I convert a Word file from html then vertical alignment is not properly displayed in it. I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` version 1.1.4322 to create word file, how to set vertical alignment in it? i am using third party javascript library.

- javascript file 1:filesarver.js
- javascript file 2:jequery.min.js

maths question formats are not proper displayed

[image]

i have using many other dll but no proper display alignment.

Comment: Please, share some code!
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.